# Switching between Light and Dark Theme from BottomSheetFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, user-interface, themes

I have a Fragment from which when clicked on a button i am opeaning a BottomSheetFragment and in that BottomSheetFragment i have switch to switch between Light and Dark Theme.

```
    binding.themesettingScLightdark.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                if(isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                } else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                }
           }
```

The Above Shown Method Crashes the App and Gives Error **"You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity"** Can Anyone Suggest Me on How to Implement This?

Answer (score 0):

`You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity` typically occurs when trying to perform UI-related operations on an `activity or fragment` that is no longer in a valid state,such as after it has been destroyed

you should use **weakReference** , this piece of code may help you

```
  binding.themesettingScLightdark.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    val activity = activityReference.get()
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.runOnUiThread {
            if (isChecked) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }
        }
    }
}
```